# Laravel Seeder error Cannot write to directory "public/storage/.."

Tags: laravel, laradock

I got this `DatabaseSeeder.php` in laravel where I create a Directory:

```
public function run()
    {
        Storage::deleteDirectory('posts');
        Storage::makeDirectory('posts');
        // Etcetera ...
    }
```

And then I run

```
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

This works flawlessly in my development environment (Laravel Homestead).

However, if I run that same command inside a Docker container using Laradock, I get the following error:

> Seeding: Database\Seeders\PostsSeeder
>
> InvalidArgumentException
>
> Cannot write to directory "public/storage/posts"
>
> at vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php:90
> 86▕     ) {
> 87▕         $dir = is_null($dir) ? sys_get_temp_dir() : $dir; // GNU/Linux / OS X / Windows compatible
> 88▕         // Validate directory path
> 89▕         if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) {   ➜  90▕             throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Cannot write to directory
> "%s"', $dir));
> 91▕         }
> 92▕
> 93▕         // Generate a random filename. Use the server address so that a file
> 94▕         // generated at the same time on a different server won't have a collision.
>
> +3 vendor frames
> database/factories/ImageFactory.php:25
>
> Faker\Generator::__call()

Why is this happening?

How do I fix it?

---

**Workaround**

To easily solve it simply create those directories:

```
$ ls -lah public/
$ cd public/ && mkdir storage && cd storage && mkdir posts && cd ../..
```

Try again

```
$ artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: have you try to give permissions to your storage folder?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because one of your "Factory" files, in the "faker" method in this case, the "posts" folder does not exist.

Faker does not have the ability to create a new folder and since the folder does not exist, I get that error.

So in this case you have to create the posts folder first. To do this, inside your "DatabaseSeeder.php" file, place the following line of code inside the run () method at the beginning:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function run()
    {
        Storage::deleteDirectory('public/posts');
        Storage::makeDirectory('public/posts');
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I create the folder using the workaround, and it works, but running `artisan migrate: refresh --seed` doesn't remove the directories but creates more.

```
public function run()
{
    Storage::deleteDirectory('posts');
    Storage::makeDirectory('posts');
    // Etcetera ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an identical error, but prior to that, I executed the following command initially.

```
php artisan storage:link
```